# Getting IndexError when using recursion to write a BinarySearch method

Tags: python, recursion

```
def binarySearch2(arr, val):
    left = 0
    right = len(arr) - 1
    mid = (left + right) // 2
    arr.sort()
    if val == arr[mid]:
        return True
    if val > arr[mid]:
        return binarySearch2(arr[mid + 1:], val)
    if val < arr[mid]:
        return binarySearch2(arr[:mid - 1], val)


for i in range(10):
    print(binarySearch2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], i))
```

It keeps telling me index out of range and i'm not sure where went wrong.

Comment: `binarySearch2` ends up getting called with an empty `arr`, so the length of that is 0. Since you compute `right = len(arr) - 1`, that makes `right` equal to `-1`. And `mid = (left + right) // 2` will also be `-1`. This is something you don't want to begin with, but trying to index an empty list with `-1` is what causes the error. Your recursive function is missing an important stop condition.

Comment: Also note that you sort the `arr` on every call to `binarySearch2`, even though it's already sorted after the first iteration. That's very inefficient.

Comment: why wolud it be an empty arr

Comment: For example, because eventually `mid` will be 1 and `mid - 1` will be 0 and `arr[:mid - 1]` will be an empty slice and you pass that to `binarySearch2` recursively.

Comment: Slicing in recursion should not be done. You might as well use `foo in lst`. Pass low, high indices as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, I pointed out that: `binarySearch2` ends up getting called with an empty `arr`, so the length of that is `0`. Since you compute `right = len(arr) - 1`, that makes `right` equal to `-1`. And `mid = (left + right) // 2` will also be `-1`. This is something you don't want to begin with, but trying to index an empty list with `-1` is what causes the error. Your recursive function is missing an important stop condition.

You asked why it would be an empty `arr`.

Your main loop calls `binarySearch2` like this on the first iteration:

```
binarySearch2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 0)
```

In the function, this means that this condition is `True`:

```
if val < arr[mid]:  # val == 0, mid == 4, 0 < arr[4]
    return binarySearch2(arr[:mid - 1], val)  # called with (arr[:4 - 1], 0)
```

Note that there's a mistake here - you pass `arr[:mid - 1]` but since the slice is already excluding the element at that index, you're slicing off one element too many. That's not the main problem though.

On this second call, the same thing happens again:

```
if val < arr[mid]:  # val == 0, mid == 1, 0 < arr[1]
    return binarySearch2(arr[:mid - 1], val)  # called with (arr[:1 - 1], 0)
```

Already, this causes `binarySearch2` to be called as `binarySearch2([], 0)`, causing the error as explained.

Even if you fix the mistake though, and change the code to this:

```
    if val < arr[mid]:
        return binarySearch2(arr[:mid], val)
```

It would still fail because the function is called with `val` being `0` and since that's a value that's not in the array, this condition still triggers and ends up calling `binarySearch2([], 0)` on the third iteration.

Your code doesn't account for the case where `val` simply isn't in the list `arr`.

A better implementation that does do this:

```
def binarySearch2(arr, val):
    def search(arr, val):
        if len(arr) == 0:
            return False
        left = 0
        right = len(arr) - 1
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        arr.sort()
        if val == arr[mid]:
            return True
        if val > arr[mid]:
            return binarySearch2(arr[mid + 1:], val)
        if val < arr[mid]:
            return binarySearch2(arr[:mid], val)
        
    arr.sort()
    return(search(arr, val))
```

This avoids sorting the list more than once, and it checks if there are values (left) in `arr` before moving on (the missing stop condition).

There's further optimisation possible. For one, you don't have to keep slicing the list - instead you could just pass along a left and right index and keep narrowing the gap between those. Of course, if you do that, you no longer need a recursive solution either, and you could do this in a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

You missed 2 things, look at your function below

```
def binarySearch2(arr, val):
    left = 0
    right = len(arr) - 1
    mid = (left + right) // 2

    # Base condition: If the left index crosses the right index, return False
    if left > right:
        return False
    arr.sort()

    if val == arr[mid]:
        return True
    if val > arr[mid]:
        return binarySearch2(arr[mid + 1:], val)
    # If the value is less than the middle element, search the left half
    if val < arr[mid]:
        return binarySearch2(arr[:mid], val)
```

**First mistake**: We know, recursion always has a base condition, otherwise it will raise an error (maximum recursion depth exceeded).
So, here we added

```
if left > right:
    return False
# This is the base condition here
```

**Second mistake**:

```
if val < arr[mid]:
   return binarySearch2(arr[:mid - 1], val)
```

Here, you don't need the `-1`. I would like to give you an example, this is for understanding the right limit:

```
list(range(1,10))
```

Result is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.
We know, the right limit is always less by 1.